# Dropzone not allowing users to drag and drop a file inside embedded browser

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using dropzone http://www.dropzonejs.com/ in IE10 and drag and drop feature is not working inside embedded browser.
The drop zone is clickable and I can upload the files to the server, thus the dropzone is initialized correctly. It is just the drag and drop feature that does not work. It shows me a cancel icon when I try to drag and drop to the dropzone. When I logout and login to the portal application then it is allowing me to drag and drag.

Any idea if I need to change any settings in IE to make the drag and drop work?

Comment: Probably just compatibility issues, IE is kind of the hater in web development

Comment: have you included the relavent polyfills for ie10?

Comment: We may be more of a help if we can see your code...

Comment: It is working in IE10, but it's not working inside the embedded browser which uses IE10. Do we have any polyfills which might fix the issue inside the embedded browser?